# How to convert a string to non string in matlab

Tags: string, matlab, matlab-guide

I have this function which takes a string as an input.

for example it takes handles.f = 'x^2'

but I want  handles.f = x^2 so that later I'll be able to do f(x) = handles.f

```
     function edit1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

     handles.f =  (get(hObject,'String'))

     handles.f

     area = rect(handles.f,handles.u,handles.l,handles.n)

     guidata(hObject,handles)
```

Function:

```
    function [ s ] = rect( f,u,l,n )
    syms x;

    f(x) = f;

    h =(u-l)/n

    z = l:h:u;

    y = f(z)

    s = 0;



   for i=1:n
   s = s+y(i);
   end

   s = h*s;

   end
```

When i call this function from command prompt like this:
          rect(x^2,5,1,4)

It works fine 
But it gives error when I call this from gui.

This is the error I get:

```
    Error using sym/subsindex (line 1558)
    Indexing input must be numeric, logical or ':'.

    Error in rect (line 8)
    f(x) = f;
```

Answer (score 1):

This goes against any advice I give myself, but if you want to do what you're asking, you'll need to use [`eval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html).  This converts any string that you input into it and it converts it into a command in MATLAB for you to execute.  If I am interpreting what you want correctly, you want to make an anonymous function that takes in `x` as an input.

Therefore, you would do this:

```
handles.f = eval(['@(x) ' get(hObject,'String')]);
```

This takes in the string stored in `hObject`, wraps it into an anonymous function, and stores it into `handles.f`.  As such, you can now do:

```
out = handles.f(x);
```

`x` is an input number.  This is one of the few cases where `eval` is required.  In general, I would not recommend using it because when code gets complicated, placing a complicated command as a string inside `eval` reduces code readability.  Also, code evaluated in `eval` is not JIT accelerated... and it's simply bad practice.

---

## Edit

Luis Mendo recommends doing [`str2func`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2func.html) to avoid `eval`... which is preferable (whew!).

So do:

```
handles.f = str2func(['@(x) ' get(hObject,'String')]);
```

Comment: Works here. @rayryeng, you could avoid `eval` by using `str2func`: `handles.f = str2func(['@(x) ' handles.f])`

Comment: @Luis Mendo  I've tried that as well :( . but its not working.

Comment: @LuisMendo - Ah very nice.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @user4129542 - This statement is nonsense: `f(x) = f;`  What exactly are you trying to do at this line?

Comment: I've given an example of how i call this function from command window

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to me.  `f` is... I'm assuming... a symbolic statement.  You declared `x` as symbolic as well, so doing `f(x) = f` doesn't make any sense.  It's the same thing as saying `f = f`.

Comment: If i remove this line then it gives me error in y=f(z)

Comment: f is not a symbolic statement. e.g it's just x^2 without any quotes as its called from command window

Comment: What if you change the variable name `f` to something else ? Lets say `fun` and then `f(x) = fun;`.